# GLSL Sphere - ray intersection geometric solution

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, raytracing

I'm trying to implement sphere ray intersection in GLSL, both the geometric and analytical solution. I'm having trouble solving the geom one, it should have something to do with how I return true or false:

```
bool hitSphere(Ray ray, Sphere sphere, float t_min, float t_max, out float t_out) {
    // Geometric solution
    float R2 = sphere.radius * sphere.radius;
    vec3 L = sphere.position - ray.origin;
    float tca = dot(L, normalize(ray.direction));
    // if(tca < 0) return false;

    float D2 = dot(L, L) - tca * tca;
    if(D2 > R2) return false;
    float thc = sqrt(R2 - D2);
    float t0 = tca - thc;
    float t1 = tca + thc;

    if(t0 < t_max && t0 > t_min) {
        t_out = t0;
        return true;
    }

    if(t1 < t_max && t1 > t_min) {
        t_out = t1;
        return true;
    }
    
    return false; 
}
```

[image]

I think the problem is with how I deal with t0 and t1 for none, one or both intersection cases.

Edit: the analytic version that does work:

```
vec3 oc = ray.origin - sphere.position;
float a = dot(ray.direction, ray.direction);
float b = dot(oc, ray.direction);
float c = dot(oc, oc) - sphere.radius * sphere.radius;

float discriminant = b * b - a * c;

if (discriminant > 0.0f) {
    if(b > 0) 
        t_out = (-b + sqrt(discriminant)) / a;
    else 
        t_out = (-b - sqrt(discriminant)) / a;
    
    if(t_out < t_max && t_out > t_min) {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
```

[image: Analytical Result]

Comment: **1)** Remove the line `if(tca < 0) return false;` the sign of the dot-p is unuseful here. **2)** `ray.direction` must be normalized. **3)** How do you pre-calculate `t_min` and `t_max`?

Comment: @Ripi2 1) this produces a weird shade over my spheres, not sure why. 2) this almost fixes it, seems to miss shadow between two spheres.  3) they are hardcoded to '0.001' and '9999.99'. I'll update the post with some pics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by `t_out`. The algorithm has to compute `t_out` in that way, that `X` is the intersected point of the ray and the surface of the sphere, for:

```non
X = ray.origin + ray.direction * t_out;
```

In the working algorithm `t_out` depends on the length of `ray.direction`. `t_out` becomes smaller, if the magnitude of the vector `ray.direction` is greater.
In the algorithm, which doesn't work, `ray.direction` is normalized.

> ```c
> float tca = dot(L, normalize(ray.direction));
> ```

Hence `t_out` is computed for a ray direction length of 1. Actually you compute a `t_out'` where `t_out' = t_out * length(ray.direction)`.

Divide `t0` respectively `t1` by the length of `ray.direction`:

```c
bool hitSphere_2(Ray ray, Sphere sphere, float t_min, float t_max, out float t_out)
{
    float R2 = sphere.radius * sphere.radius;
    vec3 L = sphere.position - ray.origin;
    float tca = dot(L, normalize(ray.direction));
    // if(tca < 0) return false;

    float D2 = dot(L, L) - tca * tca;
    if(D2 > R2) return false;
    float thc = sqrt(R2 - D2);
    float t0 = tca - thc;
    float t1 = tca + thc;

    if (t0 < t_max && t0 > t_min) {
        t_out = t0 / length(ray.direction); // <---
        return true;
    } 

    if (t1 < t_max && t1 > t_min) {
        t_out = t1 / length(ray.direction); // <---
        return true;
    }

    return false; 
}
```